# How to extract two video files from an MKV container

Tags: ffmpeg, matroska

I have a two part video.  I placed both files into an MKV container using MKVToolNix and multiplexed and produced the output file. However, the second video does not play at the end of the first.  Obviously I have made a rookie error.  So:

1. How do I change the files so that the files are linked.  There doesn't seem to be a GUI using the app version on a MAC.
2. How do I extract the video files (and subsequent audio) so that I can start over.
3. Other suggestions.  Unfortunately I have deleted the two individual videos.

MAC OS, MKVToolnix 29.0.0 and command line operators, and FFMPEG.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i input.mkv`.

Comment: Actually I figured out how to do it by trial and error.  In MKVToolNix GUI, there are various files checked.  UNchecking the ones you DONT want to save, then multiplexing will save the files back to their original state (the ones that were checked).  So I have both of them back.  What I did not do was APPEND the files but simply added them.  I fixed that and it works.

Comment: Since you found a solution you can add your own answer to your question (there may be a 2-day waiting period). If you also want a `ffmpeg` solution you can add the requested info.